# Integral over a pyramid in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: integration

$\int_E (\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_i)^p d\lambda_n$, where $E = \{x_i\in \mathbb{R}, x_i\ge 0, \sum_{i = 1}^nx_i \le 1\}$

What is the best way to find this integral? I've tried to count it as

$\int_0^1dx_1\int_0^{1-x1}dx_2\cdots\int_0^{1-\sum_{i =1}^{n - 1}x_i}(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i)^p$

But I find it really hard and impossible because there are so many numbers and it looks really bad. Can you give me a hint how to count it more easily, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @KaboMurphy's recommendation, let's warm up with the $p=0$ case, which is just the simplex's measure $\frac{1}{n!}$. If we write it as an integral, it's$$\int_0^1d^{n-1}y\int_{\max\{y_i|1\le i\le n-1\}}^1dy_n=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^1y_n^{n-1}dy_n=\frac{1}{n!}.$$For other $p$, we instead get$$\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^1y_n^{n+p-1}dy_n=\frac{(1+p/n)^{-1}}{n!}.$$

Comment: Can you explain, please, why the first integral is equal to $\frac{1}{(n - 1)!}\int_0^1y_n^{n - 1}dy_n$?

Comment: @RonaldSMerritt Induction.

Comment: Why it's true? We need $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i\le 1$, but $y_i\le y_n$ for all $i$ is not enough. I can take $y_1=\cdots=y_{n-1} = \frac{1}{2}$ and $y_n = 1$ and it will be okay for your set, but it'll be bad for $x_i$, because in this case $x_n$ must be negative. Maybe it's obvious, but I can't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Make the change of variable $y_1=x_1,y_2=x_2,...,y_{n-1}=x_{n-1}, y_n=x_1+x_2+...+x_n$.

The region changes to $0\leq y_i \leq 1$ for all $i$ and $y_i \leq y_n$ for  all $i$. Since the integrand is just $y_n^{p}$ the integral is now much easier to evaluate.